# Why TypeError: dynamodb.deleteItem is not a function?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

I am making aws serverless application with classic crud operations.
Lambdas get and update works properly. But I have a issues with delete...

```
    const key = event.pathParameters.id;
    const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    const params = {
      TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_CUSTOMER_TABLE,
      Key: {
        primaryKey: key,
      },
    };

    const result = await dynamodb.deleteItem(params).promise();
```

It fails with "TypeError: dynamodb.deleteItem is not a function".

dynamodb initialization same as in working functions and I can print it. I provided proper rights: - 'dynamodb:DeleteItem'

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing a document client here:

```
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
```

Document client has a `delete` function. From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#delete-property):

> `delete(params, callback) ⇒ AWS.Request`:
> Deletes a single item in a table by primary key by delegating to `AWS.DynamoDB.deleteItem()`

If you want to have an actual `deleteItem` function, you would want to initialize your DynamoDB client as follows:

```
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
// ...
const result = await dynamodb.deleteItem(params).promise();
```