# Best way to update data in DynamoDB via a Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I currently have an Express.js server hosted on a Lambda. I am already able to read/GET data from the table, with

```js
app.get("/profile/general", async function (req, res) {
  
  const params = {
    TableName: "users",
    Key: {
      id: `${req.user.sub}`,
    },
  };

  try {
    let userObj = await docClient.get(params).promise();
    res.json({ "data": userObj });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("error: ", err); 
    res.json({ "error": err });
  }
});
```

However, I am stuck researching the best/easiest way to do partial updates for items in DynamoDB (like objects in my "users" table).

I do not want to use a PUT method, because I don't want to replace the whole existing user object. and what would the syntax look like? This is what I have so far --

```js
app.patch("/profile/general", async function (req, res) {
  
  const params = {
    TableName: "users",
    Key: {
      id: `${req.user.sub}`,
    },
    UpdateExpression: "set age = req.body.age",
    UpdateExpression: "set country = req.body.country",
    UpdateExpression: "set skills = req.body.skills",
    ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW",
  };

  try {
    
    let newUserObj = await docClient.UpdateItem(params).promise(); 
    res.json({ "newData": newUserObj });
  } catch (err){
    console.log("error: ", err); 
    res.json({ "error": err });
  }
});
```

Is this the correct way to do a partial update with UpdateItem, passing in the necessary items to multiple "UpdateExpression" key-value pairs? The docs are a bit confusing on this.

Comment: As others have mentioned you only use one update expression. Also wanted to point out, you probably shouldn't use Express on Lambda, since an Express server will run indefinitely, and lambdas are limited to 15 minute runtime. The AWS approach wold be to use an API gateway to define the allowable request methods & paths, and proxy to your lambda function on a per-request basis.

Comment: right I see the disadvantages for express on lambda, but this is legacy code that I'm tasked to fix, so need to stick with express on lambda at least for the short term.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you should update attributes for your DynamoDB record.

```
const params = {
    TableName: "users",
    Key: {
      id: `${req.user.sub}`,
    },
    UpdateExpression : "SET age = :age, country = :country, skills = :skills"
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':age': req.body.age,
        ':country': req.body.country,
        ':skills': req.body.skills
    },
    ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW",
  };
```

In the above code, you define the values as `:<expression-attribute>`, and later in `ExpressionAttributeValues`, you provide the actual values for those attributes.

To learn more, refer AWS documentation at [Update expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.SET).

Answer (score 0):

It's one `UpdateExpression` per update, where you specify all of the updates.

```
app.patch("/profile/general", async function (req, res) {
  
  const params = {
    TableName: "users",
    Key: {
      id: `${req.user.sub}`,
    },
    UpdateExpression: `set age = ${req.body.age}, country = ${req.body.country}, skills = ${req.body.skills}`,
    ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW",
  };

  try {
    
    let newUserObj = await docClient.UpdateItem(params).promise(); 
    res.json({ "newData": newUserObj });
  } catch (err){
    console.log("error: ", err); 
    res.json({ "error": err });
  }
});
```

Comment: getting this error now in CloudWatch: TypeError: docClient.UpdateItem is not a function. So, how should I change it?

Comment: based on post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73345876/why-typeerror-dynamodb-deleteitem-is-not-a-function I added "const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();" and added "let newUserObj = await dynamodb.UpdateItem(params).promise();", but that returned the error "TypeError: dynamodb.UpdateItem is not a function". So, what am I missing/doing wrong?